# Python - how to read .pages document in python?

Tags: python, encoding

I am new to python and I am trying to read/edit .pages document in python.
I used this code:

```
with open(directory+"example.pages") as f:
    print(f.read())
```

However, the output is unreadable. I am trying to guess the root cause of the issue and it seems to be an encoding issue.

```
['PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00}\xa2\x99G^8\xfd\\\x00\x0f\x00\x00\x00\x0f\x00\x00\x12\x00\x00\x00Index/Document.iwa\x00\xfc\x0e\x00\xa75\xf0\xa54\x08\x01\x120\x08\x90N\x12\x03\x01\x00\x05\x18\xb3\x01"']
['\x03']
['\x01', '\x10\x01\x18\x00*\x18\xc2\x13\xa0\x11\x99\x11\x9c\x11\x9f\x11\x9a\x11\xa1\x11\xc3\x13\x9b\x11\x9e\x11\x9d\x11\x98\x11\x12\x03\x08\x9d\x11\x1a\x03\x08\x9f\x11"\x03\x08\xa0\x112\x03\x08\x9c\x11:\x03\x08\xa1\x11z=']
['\x05:\x03\x08\x98\x11\x1a\x02en"\x03\x08\x99\x11*\x03\x08\xc3\x132\x03\x08\x9b\x11:\x03\x08\x9a\x11@\x00J\x15Application/Blank/ISOj\x03\x08\xc2\x13\xa2\x01\x03\x08\x9e\x11\xf5\x01\xec\xd1\x14D\xfd\x01\xf6xRD\x85\x02\x8c\xc5bB\x8d\x05\x06\x00\x95\x05\x06\x00\x9d\x05\x06\xf0J\xa5\x02w\xbb', 'B\xad\x02(\x14*B\xb5\x02\x00\x00\x80?\xb8\x02\x00\xc0\x02\x00\xd0\x02\x00\xda\x02\x07mfp2462\xe2\x02\x06iso-a4\xe8\x02\x00\x0f\x08\xc2\x13\x12']
['\x08\xe0\x04\x12\x03\x01\x05\x00\x18\x00\x19\x08\xa0\x11\x12\x14\x08\xd1\x0f\x12\x05\xf90g*\x08\xd9\x11\xbd\x11\xeb\x11\xec\x11\x08\x00', '\xdf$\x05salut*']
['\x07\x05\x120\xd9\x112\x08']
['\x06\x08\x00\x10\x00\x18\x00:\x11\x15\x10\xbd\x11P\x01b\x11', '\x08\xeb\x11r\x15"\x04\x8a\x01\x11\x16', '\xec\x11\x9a\x01\x05\x17\x10\x12\x02en\xc2', '\x01D\x1c$\x08\xec\x11\x12\x1f\x08\x9b-z\x005)y\xf0L\x1d\x10\x01\x18\x01*\x08\xa5\x13\xa6\x13\xa7\x13\xa4\x13\x88\x01\x01\x90\x01\x00\x98\x01\x00\xa0\x01\x00\.....
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Pages in particular. But a text editor with that much formatting, layout etc is likely to be almost unreadable by humans.

What you are displaying is a lot of characters, most are non-printable, I see a couple commas and spaces but that is it. Have you tried look at the file in a standard text editor (like TextEditor for iOS, Notepad for Windows) to see what it is you are dealing with?